# Silverstripe model admin with extra tab

Tags: tabs, silverstripe, modeladmin

I'm creating a module for silverstripe where webapp settings can be configured and where app icons/splash screens can be uploaded.
To do this i have used the model admin to manage two DataObjects containing the icons/splash screens. This works great.

But now i have some extra fields i would like to manage from the same admin panel ('app title', 'Fullscreen app', 'statusbar' & 'minimal UI'). it would be great if it is possible to add an extra tab to the model admin where i can add these fields, problem is:

- how do i save these values
- how do i create this extra tab

i also see possibilities in extending LeftAndMain for this, but then i lose the dataobject management capabilities of the ModelAdmin.

Any tips help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra tabs in ModelAdmin are for administrating models - hence the name! The best way to strictly meet your needs within the grounds of the framework would be to have a "AppConfig" object that encapsulates your app's settings, and manage it within that ModelAdmin. Set up relationships in your other models to refer to these settings.

```
private static $managed_models = array(/*other models*/, 'AppConfig');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! i added the config as a module this works fine, but do you know if it is possible to 'remove' the gridfield and get the object's form fields straight in the tab?

Comment: The way i have it now is by extending the left and main. I looked at how the siteconfig is handled because this is similar functionality to what i was looking for

Comment: My solution is "strictly within the grounds of the framework". What you are asking for is not the intended use of ModelAdmin, which is to administer multiple models using a Gridfield. A more suitable method to implement this would be to make a class SiteConfigExtension that extends DataExtension. You would place your tabs/CMS fields in there. I can create another answer for this if that helps.